# What exactly does transformer encoder + linear layer return?

Tags: machine-learning, python, natural-language, transformers

I was following a Pytorch tutorial on transformers in language modelling ( https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html ) and I came across a bunch of questions.

**My goal is to make a sequence classifier.**
But first, let's agree on used symbols:

```
Input: [ B x N ]
Output: [ B x N x P ]
N - number of words in input sequence (words dim)
B - batch dim
P - logits
```

1. **What exactly does the particular model return?**
   When I feed it with a sequence of N length (in one batch), it returns always a B x N x P array. **But why N dim is not just size 1 but size of the input sequence?** The aim is to achieve class prediction. **If the last layer is Linear, shouldn't I get just one vector of logits instead of N vectors?** (I mean, an array of B x 1 x P)? I thought I need a whole transformer decoder block to produce N outputs and a Linear layer would just return logits (classes) (P) and batches (B). So why it returns N outputs and which one should I treat as "class"?

```
def __init__(self, ntoken, ninp, nhead, nhid, nlayers, classes, dropout=0.5):
    super(TransformerModel, self).__init__()
    self.model_type = 'Transformer'
    self.emb = nn.Embedding(ntoken, ninp)
    self.ninp = ninp
    self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoding(ninp, dropout)
    encoder_layers = TransformerEncoderLayer(ninp, nhead, nhid, dropout, batch_first=True)
    self.transformer_encoder = TransformerEncoder(encoder_layers, nlayers)
    self.decoder = nn.Linear(ninp, class_count) # two classes
```

```
def forward(self, src, src_mask=None):
    src = self.emb(src) * math.sqrt(self.ninp)
    src = self.pos_encoder(src)
    output = self.transformer_encoder(src, src_mask)
    output = self.decoder(output)
```

```
model = TransformerModel(ntoken=1000, ninp=200, nhead=8, 
   nhid=40, nlayers=2, class_count=2, dropout=0.1).to(device)
```

When fed with:

```
model(to_tensors([[22, 45, 55, 23, 30]]))
```

returns

```
tensor([[[ 2.0076, -1.0457],
         [-0.7449,  0.9649],
         [ 0.3181,  0.1880],
         [ 0.3181,  0.1880],
         [ 0.3181,  0.1880]]])
```

instead of e.g.

```
 tensor([[[ 2.0076, -1.0457]]])
```

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Please show the actual code. PyTorch's linear layer parameters are the sizes of the input and output. That's not present in your pseudocode.

Comment: It seems that (1) your questions are more general than this specific tutorial, and (2) they're not really related. Please post them as separate, focused questions instead of one mega-post.

Comment: Thank you Arya for your answer. I'll split the post into separate questions and I'll post better questions in the future. The code is actually in the link I provided, I didn't change it.

Comment: Dear Arya, I cleaned up the post and provided code and examples.